DevExtreme 1 or more validation errors when trying to Post
I am doing an app using React TypeScript with DevExtreme and .NET 8 as backend, but I am having trouble adding a datagrid which can be interacted with. The most I could get it to do was to show the DB and to delete but no posting or editing. I keep getting this error 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)' which by my understanding means I am not sending the data in the correct format from the frontend but I have no idea how to change the format I am sending data in or if its actually in the frontend. This is my first Fullstack project so I am still getting the hang of things.
Heres my frontend:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { appsettings } from "../settings/appsettings";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";
import React from "react";
import {
  Column,
  DataGrid,
  Editing,
  RemoteOperations
} from "devextreme-react/data-grid";
import "devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css";
import { createStore } from "devextreme-aspnet-data-nojquery";

export function Lista() {
  const dataSource = createStore({
    key: "idEmpleado", // Ensure this matches the key in your API response
    loadUrl: `${appsettings.apiUrl}/lista`,
    insertUrl: `${appsettings.apiUrl}/postEmpleado`,
    updateUrl: `${appsettings.apiUrl}/putEmpleado`,
    deleteUrl: `${appsettings.apiUrl}/deleteEmpleado`,
    onBeforeSend: (method, ajaxOptions) => {
     
      ajaxOptions.xhrFields = { withCredentials: true };
      ajaxOptions.headers = {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'  // Set Content-Type correctly
      };
    },
  });

  // Ensure the columns match the API response fields

  return (
    <Container className="mt-5">
      <Row>
        <Col sm={{ size: 8, offset: 2 }}>
          <h4>Lista de empleado</h4>
        </Col>
        <DataGrid
          dataSource={dataSource}
          showBorders={true}
          keyExpr="idEmpleado" // Ensure this matches your primary key
          
        >
          <Editing
            mode="row"
            allowAdding={true}
            allowDeleting={true}
            allowUpdating={true}
          />
           <RemoteOperations groupPaging={true} />
           <Column dataField="idEmpleado" caption="ID"></Column>
           <Column dataField="nombre" caption="Nombre"></Column>
           <Column dataField="correo" caption="Correo"></Column>
           <Column dataField="sueldo" caption="Sueldo"></Column>
        </DataGrid>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}


Heres my backend
 public EmpleadoController(DbcrudContext _dbContext)
 {
     dbContext = _dbContext;
 }

 [HttpGet("Lista")]
 public IActionResult Lista([FromQuery]DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
 {
     var empleados = dbContext.Empleados.AsQueryable();
     return Ok(DataSourceLoader.Load(empleados, loadOptions));
 }

 [HttpPost("postEmpleado")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> InsertOrder(FormDataCollection form)
 {
     var values = form.Get("values");

     var empleado = new Empleado();
     JsonConvert.PopulateObject(values, empleado);
     if (!TryValidateModel(empleado))
         return BadRequest(ModelState);

     dbContext.Empleados.Add(empleado);
     dbContext.SaveChanges();

     return Ok(empleado);
 }

 [HttpPut("putEmpleado")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateOrder(int key, [FromBody] IDictionary<string, object> values)
 {
     var empleado = await dbContext.Empleados.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.IdEmpleado == key);
     if (empleado == null)
         return NotFound();

     PopulateModel(empleado, values);

     if (!TryValidateModel(empleado))
         return BadRequest(ModelState);

     await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
     return Ok(empleado);
 }

 [HttpDelete("deleteEmpleado")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteOrder(int key)
 {
     var empleado = await dbContext.Empleados.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.IdEmpleado == key);
     if (empleado == null)
         return NotFound();

     dbContext.Empleados.Remove(empleado);
     await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
     
     return Ok();
 }

I have tried changing what my POST function is expecting but I don't know if its correct. While using DevExtreme I noticed that there is a CustomStore function on the data binding part of the Docs which I havent tried but I am not sure if its going to work since my problem is that the frontend is not sending the info how its supposed to.

As you can see from the 400 error code, there might be some error when sending request from client to server. I cannot reproduce the problem as your data is not shown. You could provide more code details or the log data in your project, so that members can reproduce the issue.
